# Instructions to use Mac to create USB boot to install Ubuntu 18.04 stick for PC please

Tags: 18.04

I wish to use my Mac create a USB boot stick to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my PC, as a single OS.

Edmund

Comment: Have you looked at the official doco - https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos

Answer (score 3):

- Launch Disk Utility from Applications>Utilities or Spotlight search
- Insert your USB stick and observe the new device added to Disk
  Utility
- Select the USB stick device (you may need to enable the option
  View>Show All Devices) and select `Erase` from the tool bar (or
  right-click menu)
- Set the format to `MS-DOS (FAT)` and the scheme to `GUID Partition Map`
- Check you've chosen the correct device and click `Erase`.

***Warning: Disk Utility needs to be used with caution as selecting the wrong device or partition can result in data loss.***

---

To write the ISO file to the USB stick, we're going to use a free and open source application called [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). After downloading this and clicking to mount the package, Etcher can either be run in-place or dragged into your Applications folder.

By default, recent versions of macOS block the running of applications from unidentified developers. To side-step this issue, enable ‘App Store and identified developers' in the ‘Security & Privacy' pane of System Preferences. If you are still warned against running the application, click ‘Open Anyway' in the same pane.

---

Etcher will configure and write to your USB device in three stages, each of which needs to be selected in turn:

- Select image will open a file requester from which should navigate to
  and select the ISO file downloaded previously. By default, the ISO
  file will be in your Downloads folder.
- Select drive, replaced by the name of your USB device if one is
  already attached, lets you select your target device. You will be
  warned if the storage space is too small for your selected ISO.
- Flash! will activate when both the image and the drive have been
  selected. As with Disk Utility, Etcher needs low-level access to your
  storage hardware and will ask for your password after selection.

---

After entering your password, Etcher will start writing the ISO file to your USB device.

The Flash stage of the process will show progress, writing speed and an estimated duration until completion. This will be followed by a validation stage that will ensure the contents of the USB device are identical to the source image.

When everything has finished, Etcher will declare the process a success.

Congratulations! You now have Ubuntu on a USB stick, bootable and ready to go.

---

If you want to use your USB stick with an Apple Mac, you will need to restart or power-on the Mac with the USB stick inserted while the Option/alt(⌥) key is pressed.

Comment: @user2851797 Consider I illustrated the way you need to use Etcher. So please mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

A fast way to create a bootable USB stick seems to be [the crossplatform Balena Etcher app](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).

One downloads the desired ISO and then runs Balena to flash it to the drive, creating a bootable boot device.

I found the answer before anyone else responded, but my answer won't be spam because I am a newbie so I'll get downvoted anyway :)

Edmund

Comment: You not downvoted :) However, you may choose better explaining answer by check-mark beside of it, to help other users who search for same situation.